# Find by multiple unique fields Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to find a way of how I would make a query to look for items by multiple unique fields. So for example I would like to find the item, where both "Country" and "City" is unique.

for the single field I've been using:

```
@foo = Foo.where(created_at: from..to).to_a.uniq{ |foo| foo.bar }
```

where `bar` is the unique field in my `Foo` table.

How would I get `Foo` where `bar` and `baz` fields are unique?

Comment: Why don't you try chaining multiple `uniq` method calls?

Comment: Well.. I got downvote as I don't understand your example code.. :) Can you tell it more specifically.. so that I can help you also,.. :D

Comment: You want to find records that are unique in your database or you want to remove duplicates?

Comment: What is your DB client name ? This is really worth to mention..

Comment: trying to find unique ones @Fer

Comment: What is you DB client name ??

Comment: my database is postgres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `unique` method with an arary as return:

```
@foo = Foo.where(created_at: from..to).to_a.uniq{ |foo| [foo.bar, foo.baz] }
```

Comment: of course on postgres you also can use a proper select distinct clause

Answer (score 1):

Do use [DISTINCT ON](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/)

```
 Foo.where(created_at: from..to)
    .select("DISTINCT ON (foo) foo, bar")
    .order("foo, bar")
```

Here is an example to show how this query gives unique records on multiple columns. Lets create a table :

```
app_development=# select * from clients;
 id | age | name |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+-----+------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 |  26 | Arup | 2015-03-23 08:56:45.968966 | 2015-03-23 08:56:45.968966
  2 |  26 | Arup | 2015-03-23 08:56:57.269637 | 2015-03-23 08:56:57.269637
  3 |  25 | Ayan | 2015-03-23 08:57:06.956179 | 2015-03-23 08:57:06.956179
(3 rows)

appdevelopment=# SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) name, age FROM "clients"   ORDER BY name, age;
 name | age
------+-----
 Arup |  26
 Ayan |  25
(2 rows)
```

Exactly same you can do in Rails too:

```
2.1.2 :005 > Client.select("DISTINCT ON (name) name, age").order("name, age")
  Client Load (0.9ms)  SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) name, age FROM "clients"   ORDER BY name, age
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Client id: nil, age: 26, name: "Arup">, #<Client id: nil, age: 25, name: "Ayan">]>
2.1.2 :006 > Client.select("DISTINCT ON (name) name, age").order("name, age").map { |r| [r.name, r.age] }
  Client Load (0.5ms)  SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) name, age FROM "clients"   ORDER BY name, age
 => [["Arup", 26], ["Ayan", 25]]
```

Comment: what is the difference between `DISTINCT ON` and the `uniq`?

Comment: @knowbody `#uniq` is an alias of [`distinct`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/uniq). But as you used `to_a`, you were using `Array#uniq`, not the SQL _distinct_. But `disntict_on` is Postgres feature.

Comment: @knowbody check now,, and do it as much as you can using `SQL`.. :D